# Finding the nearest location to a test point

Tags: optimization, coordinate-systems

I have about 2000+ sets of geographical coordinates (lat, long). Given one coordinate I want to find the closest one from that set. My approach was to measure the distance but hundreds of requests per second can be a little rough to the server doing all that math.

What is the best-optimized solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you’re describing here is called a ***nearest neighbor search*** and there are lots of good data structures that support fast nearest neighbor lookups. The ***k-d tree*** is a particularly simple and fast choice and there are many good libraries out there that you can use. You can also look into alternatives like vantage-point trees or quadtrees if you’d like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you suggest some libraries because I have no experience

Comment: I don’t have any specific libraries to recommend, but I imagine some quick Googling would work wonders here. :-) Good luck!